# MFC : Create shapes in a window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am creating an application for the purpose of learning. I have a class for creating the window.
I am creating a separate class that would help draw different shapes on the window. However, I am not able to draw on the window. It works fine when we keep all the code in the same class. But I want to keep the classes separate.

Here's the code:
MainFrame.h

```
#include "afxwin.h"
class CMainFrame :  public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CMainFrame(void);
    ~CMainFrame(void);
    static CRect GetClientRectangle();
protected:
    int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT);
    void OnShowWindow(BOOL, UINT);
    void OnActivate(UINT, CWnd*, BOOL);
    void OnPaint();
    void OnSize(UINT, int, int);
    void OnSizing(UINT, LPRECT);
    void OnMove(int, int);
    void OnMoving(UINT, LPRECT);
    void OnClose();
    void OnDestroy();
    void OnLButtonUp(UINT, CPoint);    
    void DrawRectangle(CDC*);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

MainFrame.cpp

```
#include "MainFrame.h"
#include "Shapes.h"
#include <sstream>

CMainFrame::CMainFrame(void)
{
    Create(NULL, _T("Windows Application Tester"),WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CRect(120,100,700,480),NULL);
}
CMainFrame::~CMainFrame(void)
{
}


int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    // Call the base class to create the window
    if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1) {
        MessageBox(_T("The window was not created!!!"));
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(_T("The window has been created!!!"));
        return 0;
    }
}
void CMainFrame::OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus) 
{
    CFrameWnd::OnShowWindow(bShow, nStatus);
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    //ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
void CMainFrame::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized) 
{
    CFrameWnd::OnActivate(nState, pWndOther, bMinimized);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    switch( nState )
    {
    case WA_ACTIVE:
        SetWindowText(_T("This window has been activated, without the mouse!"));
        break;
    case WA_INACTIVE:
        SetWindowText(_T("This window has been deactivated and cannot be changed now!!"));
        break;
    case WA_CLICKACTIVE:
        SetWindowText(_T("This window has been activated using the mouse!!!"));
        break;
    }    
}
void CMainFrame::OnPaint() 
{
    CFrameWnd::OnPaint();

    CShapes shape;
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect client;
    GetClientRect(&client);
    shape.DrawRectangle(&dc, client);
    SetWindowText(_T("The window has been painted<==>"));
}
void CMainFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) //nType-> window state; cx,cy->new width,height
{
    CFrameWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    char *MsgToShow = new char[20];
    char *MsgCoord  = new char[20];
    switch(nType) {
    case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
        strcpy(MsgToShow, "Minimized ");
        break;
    case SIZE_MAXIMIZED:
        strcpy(MsgToShow, "Maximized ");
        break;
    case SIZE_RESTORED:
        strcpy(MsgToShow, "Restored ");
        break;
    case SIZE_MAXHIDE:
        strcpy(MsgToShow, "Maximized Not Me ");
        break;
    case SIZE_MAXSHOW:
        strcpy(MsgToShow, "Restored Not Me ");
        break;
    }
    sprintf(MsgCoord, "Left = %d | Top = %d", cx, cy);
    strcat(MsgToShow, MsgCoord);
    SetWindowText(CString(MsgToShow));
}
void CMainFrame::OnSizing(UINT nType, LPRECT lpRect)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnSizing(nType,lpRect);
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    SetWindowText(_T("Resized"));
}
void CMainFrame::OnMove(int x, int y) 
{
    CFrameWnd::OnMove(x, y);
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<"Window moved to " << x << ", " << y;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    SetWindowText(CString(s.c_str()));
}
void CMainFrame::OnMoving(UINT nSide, LPRECT lpRect)
{       
    CFrameWnd::OnMoving(nSide, lpRect);
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<"Window moving to " << lpRect->top << ", " << lpRect->left;
    std::string s = ss.str();
    SetWindowText(CString(s.c_str()));;
}
void CMainFrame::OnClose() 
{
    CFrameWnd::OnClose();

}
void CMainFrame::OnDestroy()
{
    CFrameWnd::OnDestroy();
    MessageBox(_T("Window Destroyed"));
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
}
void CMainFrame::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
    CFrameWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    MessageBox(_T("Hello"));
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame,CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SHOWWINDOW()
    ON_WM_ACTIVATE()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
    ON_WM_SIZING()
    ON_WM_MOVE()
    ON_WM_MOVING()
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    ON_WM_DESTROY()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Here's the Shape part:

Shape.h

```
class CShapes
{
public:
    CShapes(void);
    ~CShapes(void);
    //void DrawArc(CDC*);
    void DrawRectangle(CDC*, CRect);
    /*void DrawRoundRectangle(CDC*);
    void DrawEllipse(CDC*);
    void DrawChord(CDC*);*/
};
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shapes.h"

CShapes::CShapes(void)
{
}
CShapes::~CShapes(void)
{
}

void CShapes::DrawRectangle(CDC* dc, CRect client)
{
    dc->DrawText(_T("Rectangle with 1 call to CDC::Rectangle()"),-1,&client,
        DT_BOTTOM | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER );
    client.DeflateRect(100,100);
    dc->Rectangle(&client);
}
```

Here's Main.cpp file which creates the object for initializing the window.

```
#include "MainFrame.h"
class CIntroToMFCApp : public CWinApp {
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CMainFrame *Frame = new CMainFrame();
        m_pMainWnd = Frame;
        Frame->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
        Frame->UpdateWindow();      
        //AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessageW(WM_CLOSE);
        return TRUE;
    }
};
CIntroToMFCApp MyApplication;
```

Please tell me where I need to make changes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : Answer rewritten

Ok, I did a quick test with a brand new MFC project in VS2010.

Suppress the line

```
 CFrameWnd::OnPaint();
```

With it, no text/rectangle.
Without it, text/recatngle.

When you generate a project with the "wizard", you'ill notice that the OnPaint Handler contains:

```
// Do not call CWnd::OnPaint() for painting messages
```

Comment: Using `CDC* pDC = BeginPaint(&ps);` and `CPaintDC dc(this);` perform the same operation. `CPaintDC` is more appropriate, since you cannot possibly forget to call `EndPaint()`. I don't see how this is any different from the code posted by the OP (minus the missing call to `EndPaint()`).

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, learned something today, thanks. But what is the OP's problem, then?

Comment: Possibly - and I'm only guessing here - the call to the base class `CFrameWnd::OnPaint();`. I think this **validates** the entire invalid region, leaving no more painting to be done. This could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

The Rectangle is drawn with the pen and filled with the brush you select before calling CDC::Rectangle. But you haven't provided those. There is an example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8w4fzfxf.aspx

You will have similar issues with DrawText, where you have not set the text color or background mode prior to drawing.

I'm not sure about the issue raised by IInspectable, but it won't do any harm to comment out the call to CFrameWnd::OnPaint(). It is either useless or harmful.

Comment: DC have default values for most object types (color, font, pen...)

Comment: @manuell is right. These will give a style to the rectangle but will not help in draw.